# RFID 13.56, can you include a tab in the data string?

Tags: rfid

I have tried to find the answer by googling but I can't find anything about it.

On a normal barcode you can include a tab `\t` in the datastring making it possible to write username and password in two separate fields.

Is that also possible on RFID 13.56? Can you write `username\tpassword` on the tag and have that as your method to log in to software on a computer?

Answer (score 0):

You cant find an answer on google, cause there isn't a singleton. A programmable tag contains an EEPROM the encoding is your choice.